# Asp.net email sending on publish but not development

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient

I am developing an application  with asp.net mvc. And I need to send email when an action populated.

```
public class MyController : Controller{

   public ActionResult Create(string name){

        // create and save to database

        // if success 
        // select admin emails from database.
        // create email content and subject.
        // send email to admins.
   }
}
```

But I want to automatically activate sending mechanism after published my project. In development, I do not need to send email on Create action.

Is there any setting to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle those kind of scenarios you should use Dependency Injection (I personally used it in 99.9% of the projects because this is the only way you can unit test it). Dependency Injection library ([Autofac](http://autofac.org/), [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/windsor/), [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html) and others) allows you to resolve dependencies in run time base on some configuration. For example you you have a communication service that is responsible to send emails:

```
public interface ICommuniucationService
{
    void SendEmail(....);
}

public class CommunicationService : ICommuniucationService
{
    public void SendEmail(...)
    {
        //real implementation of sending email
    }
}

public class FakeCommunicationService : ICommuniucationService
{
    public void SendEmail(...)
    { 
       //do nothing.
       return;
    }
}
```

My controller is going to have a private property of type ICommuniucationService that is going to be instantiated by the dependency injection library via constructor injection:

```
public class MyController : Controller{

   //this will be resolved in runtime(either CommuniucationService or FakeCommunicationService )
   private readonly ICommuniucationService EmailSvc;

   // Use constructor injection for the dependencies
   public MyController(ICommuniucationService svc) {
       this.EmailSvc= svc;       
   }

   public ActionResult Create(string name){

        // create and save to database

        // if success 
        // select admin emails from database.
        // create email content and subject.

        this.EmailSvc.SendEmail(...)

        //The action code doesn't change neither for 
   }
}
```

When configuring dependency injection container you could do something like this ([Simple injector example](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) similar to this ):

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {       
    var container = new Container();  
#if DEBUG
   container.Register<ICommuniucationService, FakeCommuniucationService>(Lifestyle.Singleton); 
#else
   container.Register<ICommuniucationService, CommuniucationService>(Lifestyle.Singleton); 
#endif         

    container.Verify();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

So with this configuration when your project runs with DEBUG mode you are registering `FakeCommuniucationService` which doesn't send emails, while when you run in RELEASE mode (that you should use when you publish your application) real `CommuniucationService` is registered

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HttpRequest.IsLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx) Property.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Create(string name)
   {
       if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal) { ... }
       else { ... }
   }
}
```